# C difference between (++variable) and (variable++)

Tags: c, loops, syntax, operators

I have some C code here:

```
char *cat_copy(char *dest, char *src)
{
    char *start = dest;

    while (*++dest);    //increment unless it can't anymore.

    while (*src++)
    {
        *dest = *(src - 1);
        dest++;
    }
    return start;
}
```

I had to use `while (*++dest)` to get it to work, instead of `while (*dest++)`.

I read : ["--" operator in while ( ) loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897573/operator-in-while-loop) and in my mind it made sense to use `while (*dest++)`.

Why doesn't it work with `*dest++`?  And what is the difference between `*dest++` and `*++dest`.

Comment: In this while loop, as far as I understand, you want to check if you're still in bound of the string. If you do dest++, it first check the place he is now, and then increment it by one, which may cause out of bounds error inside the loop, but ++dest first increment the string index and then checks if it's still in bounds...Hope I could get you understand

Comment: I thought after both loops complete I end up on the same char : '0', I tried to log what happened with printf everywhere and both version reported that after the loop we were at char '0' so I'm confused

Comment: I think that when it's dest++, you don't end with '0' but with one character "after" it, which is an invalid memory space (segmentation fault)

Comment: To keep incrementing unless it can't anymore ? If there isn't one isn't the compiler gonna think that the line under the while loop is inside the while ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (*++dest);
```

This increments `dest` and then checks if it points to the terminating null byte of the string. At the end of the string, this will leave `dest` pointing to the terminating null byte

```
while (*dest++);
```

This increments `dest` and then checks if it *did point* to the terminating null, *before the incrementing happened*. At the end of the string, this will leave `dest` pointing to the character *after* the terminating null.

Since in the following copying part you want to overwrite the original terminating null of `dest`, the first version works better.

The first version still has a bug though. It *always* increments `dest` at least once, which is not the correct thing to do if `dest` starts out as the empty string. Separating the `*dest` check from the `dest++` increment makes the loop clearer and handles this case correctly:

```
while (*dest)
   dest++;
```

Comment: Thank you very much I understand perfectly now, what would you suggest to make it complete, that I check first if empty string ?

Answer (score 4):

```
while (*++dest);
```

is like

```
do {
  dest++; // or ++dest
} while (*dest);
```

where as

```
while (*dest++);
```

is like

```
while (*dest) {
  dest++;
}
dest++;
```

You need to copy all the `char`s including the NUL byte.

With `while (*++dest);` you are incrementing `dest` before dereferencing it.  Had the *first* `char` been the NUL byte, you would have missed it and looped on an on.

Comment: So the second one goes one char too far ?

Comment: Good answer I upvoted you but I liked the answer who explained with sentences better ! Thanks anyway!

Comment: The post code fails as it skips testing the first byte.  Suggest `while (*src) { *dest++ = *src++; }; *dest = '\0';`.

Comment: +1 Very good explanation , i cant voteup as i have exceeded the number of voteups.

Comment: @ItsASecret  Sometimes the best answers show up _much_ later.